# Why doesn't my post post the image in MVC.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Input in the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Articles", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
 <td><input type="file" name="Img" id="Img"/></td>
}
```

Model of my image object:

```
  public class Image
  {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Contents { get; set; }
    public byte[] Img { get; set; }
    public int Articleid { get; set; }
  }
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    } 

    //
    // POST: /Articles/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Article article , HttpPostedFileBase img)
    {
      var whatisPosted = Request.Form.AllKeys.ToList();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Articles.Add(article);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        return View(article);
    }
```

So what is posted don't have the image ..... don't know why ... but the other stuff I post is posted correctly .... so why is it not working? -_-

Comment: What is in `HttpPostedFileBase img`?  Also, you have an `Image` model above but aren't using it anywhere.

Comment: I will use when im gonna create it .... but for now im just trying to post the data of the image ....

Comment: HttpPostedFileBase is null to .... i aded this just for seeing if there wold be empty ... and it empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get posted image from `HttpContext.Request.Files["Img"]`

```
HttpPostedFileBase img = HttpContext.Request.Files["Img"];
```

Edit:

Also you can just rename your HttpPostedFileBase parameter of the Crate action to match the "name" attribute in your html.

```
public ActionResult Create(Article article , HttpPostedFileBase Img) <-- capital "I"
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your View does not contain a submit button - you'll need one (unless you use `.submit()` from the jQuery library, for example). This sends a HTTP POST request to the server -- your Controller is then able to handle it.

The `article` object will always be null as it's never initalised. Try the following code:

View:

```
@model ArticleFormViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Articles", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
  <td>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ImageFile)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ImageFile, new { type = "file" })
  </td>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="submit" />
}
```

Model(s):

```
public class ArticleFormViewModel
{
  [AllowHtml]
  public string Contents { get; set; }

  [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
  public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
  public int ImageID { get; set; }
  ...
}

public class Article
{
  public int ArticleID { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
  ArticleFormViewModel Model = new ArticleFormViewModel();
  return View(Model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ArticleFormViewModel Model)
{
 if(ModelState.IsValid)
 {
   if(Model.ImageFile != null)
   {
     var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/articles"), Model.ImageFile.FileName);
     try
     {
       Model.ImageUpload.SaveAs(imagePath);

       //Perhaps then save Entity to database using an ORM?
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
       //Do something..
     }
   }
 }

 return View(Model);
}
```

Comment: I'm suprised this isnt the chosen answer!